# Weird Chinese letters in IE when looking for a source of xml page

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

1. Open this link in IE: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml

You will see this page:

[image: screenshot]

2. Press CTRL+U (or right click -> View Source)

You will see the source code, just like it's meant to be.

[image: screenshot]

Now we will do almost same thing but a little bit differently. We will save the xml file to our PC along with the xsl file and view it again with IE.

1. Open same link in Chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml

Why with chrome? Because IE doesn't provide to save an XML file with a style.

2. Press CTRL+S and save it to somewhere in your PC.
3. Open the saved file with IE.

You will see that there will be only text, no styling. That's expected because its an XML document without a style.

[image: screenshot]

4. Open this link in Chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog.xsl

This is it's style file, save it to same place you saved the xml file before.

5. Now open the cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml file with IE again. Now it is shown with styling, just like it is shown before. Good.
6. Press CTRL+U to view the source.

BOM! You get this Chinese letters.

[image: screenshot]

Why?

Comment: Don't use w3schools at all! http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @uL1, not relevant to question mate.